# How does one perform the exp() operation element-wise in Juila?

Tags: julia, elementwise-operations

I'm new to Julia and this seems like a straight-forward operation but for some reason I am not finding the answer anywhere.

I have been going through some tutorials online and they simply use exp(A) where A is a nxm matrix but this gives me a DimensionMismatch error.

I looked through the documentation on the official website in the [elementary functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/index.html) as well as the [linear algebra](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Linear-Algebra-1) section and googled it multiple times but can't find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In julia, operations on matrices treat the matrix as an object rather than a collection of numbers. As such `exp(A)` tries to perform the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) which is only defined for square matrices. To get element-wise operations on matrices, you use broadcasting which is done with the dot operator. Thus here, you want `exp.(A)`.

This design is used because it allows any scalar operation to be done on arrays
rather than just the ones built in to the language.

Comment: I keep gettting the following error when I try this: `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching exp(::Vector{Int64})` What is going on?

Comment: what's your code? presumably you need `exp.` somewhere where you have `exp`

Answer (score 9):

The broadcasting operator `.` always changes a function to "element-wise". Therefore the answer is `exp.(A)`, just like `sin.(A)`, `cos.(A)`, or `f.(A)` for any user-defined `f`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer, one might also wish to consider the broadcast operator with function piping:

```
A = rand(-10:10, 3, 3)

A .|> sin .|> inv
```